# Pandas collapse multiple rows into one by selecting the most probable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

#### Problem

My **first** DataFrame consists of the following:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 'C_A'], [2, 'C_B'], [3, 'C_C'], [3, 'C_D'], [4, 'C_F']],
    columns=['time', 'category']
)

   time category
0     1      C_A
1     2      C_B
2     3      C_C
3     3      C_D
4     4      C_F
```

There are **some** rows that have **multiple time entries**.

Now my second df is a probability distribution **at each time for each category**:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.7, 0.3, 0.], [1, 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
    columns=['C_A', 'C_B', 'C_C', 'C_D', 'C_F']
)

   C_A  C_B  C_C  C_D  C_F
0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.7  0.3  0.0
3  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

For the rows with one single time, I want to **keep them as they are**.

But, for example, for the **3rd** and **4th** row of `df1` I'd like to keep only 1 of the multiple rows, to be the one **with
the highest probability**.

The final result would be:

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 'C_A'], [2, 'C_B'], [3, 'C_C'], [4, 'C_F']],
    columns=['time', 'category']
)

   time category
0     1      C_A
1     2      C_B
2     3      C_C
3     4      C_F
```

#### Question

How can I collapse these multiple rows when they do appear, and keep the row with the greatest probability based on my other DataFrame?

Comment: does `time` column in `df1` indicate the index of `df2`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to extract the value (probability) from `df2` using `df1.time` as index and `df2.category` as columns. Then, you can sort the values and drop duplicates.

The first step is basically a case of the deprecated `lookup` function. You can use numpy indexing instead:

```
row_idx, col_idx = df2.index.get_indexer(df1.time-1), df2.columns.get_indexer(df1.category)

(df1.assign(prob=df2.to_numpy()[row_idx, col_idx])
    .sort_values(['time', 'prob'])
    .drop_duplicates('time', keep='last')
)
```

Output:

```
   time category  prob
0     1      C_A   1.0
1     2      C_B   1.0
2     3      C_C   0.7
4     4      C_F   0.0
```